# Cleanup method is not working in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am testing a todo application that I built in React js and for testing, I am using React Testing Library problem is that when I run my first test it affects the others test written below him, I tried many possible solutions but can't find the solution of this

**Here is my AddTodo Component**

```
const AddTodo = () => {
  //get store todo list from local storage
  const getTodoList = () => {
    let result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));
    if (result) return result;
    else return [];
  };

  //define states
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState(getTodoList());
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(todoList.length);

  //Click Handler
  const handleClick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    let obj = { id: counter, todo: todo };
    setTodoList([...todoList, obj]);
    setTodo("");
  };

  //Adding Todo Items in Local Storage
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(todoList));
  }, [todoList]);

  //Input Form Change Handler
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTodo(e.target.value);
  };

  //remove completed todos
  const removeTodo = (todoId) => {
    let list = getTodoList();
    let result = list.filter((l) => {
      return l.id !== todoId;
    });
    setTodoList(result);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <header>Todo App</header>
      <div className={style.inputField}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add your new todo"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={todo}
          data-testid="input"
        />
        <button onClick={handleClick} data-testid="btn">
          <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <ul className={style.todoList}>
        {todoList.map((l, index) => (
          <Todo todo={l.todo} key={index} onClick={removeTodo} id={l.id} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Add Todo Component Test**

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import AddTodo from "../AddTodo";

beforeEach(() => {
  render(<AddTodo />);
});

/**
 * Helper Methods
 * These methods get the most frequntly used elements for testing
 * */

const addTask = (task) => {
  const inputEl = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Add your new todo");
  const btnEl = screen.getByTestId("btn");

  task.forEach((el) => {
    fireEvent.change(inputEl, { target: { value: el } });
    fireEvent.click(btnEl);
  });
};

const removeTask = (task) => {
  task.forEach((tsk) => {
    fireEvent.click(tsk);
  });
};

/**
 * Unit Testing
 * Test the each part of component
 **/

describe("Unit Testing of Component", () => {
  it("should be empty by deafult", () => {
    const inputEl = screen.getByTestId("input");
    expect(inputEl.value).toBe("");
  });

  it("should change input value", () => {
    const inputEl = screen.getByTestId("input");
    fireEvent.change(inputEl, {
      target: {
        value: "hello i am test",
      },
    });
    expect(inputEl.value).toBe("hello i am test");
  });

  it("should empty input field after each click", () => {
    const inputEl = screen.getByTestId("input");
    const btnEl = screen.getByTestId("btn");
    fireEvent.change(inputEl, {
      target: {
        value: "hello test1 ",
      },
    });

    fireEvent.click(btnEl);
    expect(inputEl.value).toBe("");
  });
});

/**
 * Integration Testing
 * Test 2 components 'Todo' and 'AddTodo'
 **/

describe("Integration Testing of Component", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });

  it("should add value to todo List", () => {
    const inputEl = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Add your new todo");
    const btnEl = screen.getByTestId("btn");
    fireEvent.change(inputEl, {
      target: {
        value: "hello test1",
      },
    });

    fireEvent.click(btnEl);
    const listEl = screen.getByText(/hello test1/i);
    expect(listEl).toBeInTheDocument;
  });

  it("should add multiple value to todo List", () => {
    addTask(["test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4", "test 5"]);
    const listEl = screen.getAllByTestId("btn2");
    expect(listEl.length).toBe(5);
  });

  it("should remove when click on check button", () => {
    const listEl = screen.getAllByTestId("btn2");

    removeTask(listEl);

    expect(listEl.length).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

**Todo Component**

```
  return (
    <>
      <li data-testid="title">
        {props.todo}
        <span className={style.icon} data-testid="icon">
          <i
            className="fas fa-check"
            data-testid="btn2"
            onClick={() => {
              props.onClick(props.id);
            }}
          ></i>
        </span>
      </li>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `localstorage` methods from your `AddTodo` component. I think this is what is causing the unexpected behavior. (The component is reset properly but when rerendered, it reads from localstorage)

If that works, you can readd the localstorage usage and mock it in your tests:

```
describe("Todo tests", ()=>{
  const setItemMock = jest.fn();
  const getItemMock = jest.fn();
  beforeEach(() => {
    Storage.prototype.setItem = setItemMock;
    Storage.prototype.getItem = getItemMock;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    setItemMock.mockRestore();
    getItemMock.mockRestore();
  });
  // your tests
});
```

With this, you can also check if the localstorage functions were invoked or not: `expect(getItemMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`

Comment: Thanks your solution worked, I wonder how I miss this simple mistake, One thing can you tell me how is this mock thing working?

Comment: @AsfandSaddiqui basically, this replaces the `localstorage.get` and `localstorage.set` functions with functions that can be called without an error, but do not do anything. (Except record how often and with which argument they were called). For more detail please read up in the jest docs or look for some tutorials.